# How i can change .env variables in Laravel 6.0 by controller?

Tags: php, laravel

I am making a system on Laravel where i want to give rights to admin to change some .env variables like mail settings(server or port) etc. How can i do it?

Comment: Temporary or permanent?

Answer (score 1):

I have created a method `changeEnv` for same:

```
public function changeEnv($data = array()){
      if(count($data) > 0){

        // Read .env-file
        $env = file_get_contents(base_path() . '/.env');

        // Split string on every " " and write into array
        $env = preg_split('/\s+/', $env);;

        // Loop through given data
        foreach((array)$data as $key => $value){

          // Loop through .env-data
          foreach($env as $env_key => $env_value){

            // Turn the value into an array and stop after the first split
            // So it's not possible to split e.g. the App-Key by accident
            $entry = explode("=", $env_value, 2);

            // Check, if new key fits the actual .env-key
            if($entry[0] == $key){
              // If yes, overwrite it with the new one
              $env[$env_key] = $key . "=" . $value;
            } else {
              // If not, keep the old one
              $env[$env_key] = $env_value;
            }
          }
        }

        // Turn the array back to an String
        $env = implode("\n", $env);

        // And overwrite the .env with the new data
        file_put_contents(base_path() . '/.env', $env);

        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
```

usage :

```
$this->changeEnv(['lastEvaluatedKeyAU' => 'randomID-or-randomString']);
```

Comment: how to fill $data?

Comment: just pass key-value pair as Array

Comment: You should never be modifying the `.env` file for any reason programmatically. It's meant to be a _static_ _cacheable_ resource.

Comment: i need to fill array from user values he/she entered in form. In which variable should i put the respective value. for example if i read MAIL_PORT from user i should put it in $data['MAIL_PORT'] ?

Comment: I know DigitalDrifter. But this is a requirment so i have to do it.

Comment: @FaizanAhmad like DigitalDrifter said, you should be pulling those values from the database if they are going to be dynamic. If the port is dependent on the user, then you could have a user_settings table that stores the port value and then read that value when you need to set the port.